# How can i use other apps api in my own project?

Tags: django

Let's say i wanted to use the weather api to implement in my django code. I know how to create Rest-api in django but how can i use api of other sources to django itself?

Comment: yes, you can definitely use some third party api in your django app.You can use `requests` package to make http requests

Comment: @RajanSharma do you have any links or some example you have done to show how it's done?

Comment: [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-weather-app-in-django) would help you do your task